# how to see if a letter char *c exist in word char s[30]?

Tags: arrays, string, if-statement, char, strcmp

> here is code and i need help to find the place of letter.The strcmp is not working and i dont now where is the proble to fix.

```
#include <string.h>


int main(void)
    {
    
    
    char s[30]="fiordi";
    char *c;
    int cp,i,place;

    printf("Enter char: ");
    scanf("%s",&c);

    
    for(i=0; i<6; i++){
   
     cp=strcmp(s[i],c);  
       if( cp == 0 ){
          place=i;
       }

    }

    printf("the place is :%d",place);

    }
```

Comment: I wrote you the example because your piece of code has more than one problem: you pass to scanf() the address of "c" which is an uninitialized pointer (char * c), also, always in scanf, you use the "%s" formatting which at least writes to the address you passed it 2 characters: the character you entered and a '\0' character (end of the string using "%s"). Your luck is that a pointer is wider than 2 characters. If you had written "hello world" during the input instead of entering one character, your program would not only have malfunctioned due to the 'if' but would have really crashed.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <string.h>                                                                
#include <stdio.h>                                                                 
                                                                               
                                                                               
 int main(void)                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    char s[30]="fiordi";                                                       
    size_t s_len = strlen(s);                                                  
    int place, c;                                                              
                                                                               
    printf("Enter char: ");                                                    
    scanf("%c",&c);                                                            
                                                                                                                                                     
    for(place = 0; place < s_len; place++)                                     
        if(s[place] == (char)c)                                            
             break;                                                     
    if(place == s_len)                                                         
        printf("\nchar not found in string\n");                            
    else                                                                       
        printf("the place of char in \"%s\" is in position %d", s, place); 
                                                                               
}
```

Comment: and you  thx so much !

Answer (score -1):

`strcmp` compares *strings*, not *characters*. Without going into the details of why it doesn't work, you could just compare the characters directly:

```
   if(s[i] == c[0] ){
      place=i;
   }
```

Comment: gg thx so much!

Comment: The fix may not work. The OP declared 'c' as "char *c" without initialization (c points to nothing) and then passed its address to scanf(), so now the pointer instead of an address contains what was entered in input + '\0' :) In fact your fix works if you change it like this: if(s[i] == &c[0]). Perhaps it is better for the OP to change the data type of 'c' and the formatting of scanf().